# How to validate comma-separated string using Regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need to validate my c# model class.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Comma Separated String Required")]
[RegularExpression(@"", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Comma Separated String.")]
[RegularExpression(@"", ErrorMessage = "Duplicate Code.")]
public string CommaSeparatedString { get; set; }
```

I just tried the following regex, but it is not working for me.

```
((\s+)??(\d[a-z]|[a-z]\d|[a-z]),?)+?$
```

In my case, `CommaSeparatedString` can be:

```
ASAEW1,ASAEW2,ASA,S4,ASAEW5,ASAEW6,ASAEW7 - Valid

ASAEW1,ASAEW2,ASA,S4,ASAEW5,ASAEW6,ASAEW7,ASAEW6 - Invalid - Duplicate ASAEW6

ASAEW1,ASAEW2,ASA,S4,ASAEW5,ASAEW6,ASAEW7, - Invalid - Comma at end

ASAEW1,ASAEW2,,ASA,S4,ASAEW5,ASAEW6,ASAEW7 - Invalid - No value between 2,3 comma
```

The above requirement should happen. Is there any possible way to check duplicates in comma-separated String? I need to show `'Duplicates code'` error message if `CommaSeparatedString` consists of duplicates. How can I do this?

Comment: Not a full answer, but I think FluentValidation library will work wonders here, where you can write your custom validation rules. With RegEx only you will not go far though, I think you need to write a bit of code to split the arguments and check their existence and if there are any duplicates

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a regex magician, but puzzled together something that might work for you [here](https://regex101.com/r/Z5lYNj/2):

```
^((([A-Z]+\d*)(?!.*,\3\b)),)*[A-Z]+\d*$
```

So to visualize this:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

In steps:

- `^(((`  - Start string ancor followed by three capture groups
- `[A-Z]+\d*` - Third capture group must exist out of capitals (at least one) followed by as many digits as possible
- `(?!.*,\3\b)` - Negative lookahead to make sure that previously found pattern will **not** have a duplicate further down the line.
- `),)*` - Closing group 2 followed by a comma and closing group 1 which then must occur `*` as many times as possible
- `[A-Z]+\d*` - The last bit is repeating the same pattern we were looking for in group 3
- `$` - End string ancor

I'm not the best at explaining either but I hope it's clear enough and working (hoping backreferences are allowed within c# as I have no experience in that) =)

Comment: Sir how can I return separate model validation for `Invalid Comma Separated String.` and `Comma Separated String Required` ? Thanks anyway your answer sir

Comment: @Adam, I wouldn't be able to help you with `c#` other that the above as the pattern should work for all 4 cases your have put up. Sorry if it's not helpfull.

Comment: Thank u, sir. And sir can you please provide me another Regex to check 1.Comma at end 2. Comma at the beginning, 3. No value between commas. Because I planned to check the duplicate part without regex.

Comment: Please help me, sir, How can I write a regex to check only these three validation. 1.Comma at end 2. Comma at the beginning, 3. No value between commas

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at custom validations for your model, using either the [ASP.Net (Core?) framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ivalidatableobject) or the [FluentValidation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/index.html) Nuget package.

For a solution depending only on the framework, I write a sample that might work for you or at least get you started:

```cs
public class MyModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public string CommaSeparatedString { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (CommaSeparatedString.EndsWith(","))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Invalid Comma Separated String - Comma at end");
        }

        var splitCodes = CommaSeparatedString.Split(",");
        var setOfCodes = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var code in splitCodes)
        {
            if (code.Trim() == String.Empty)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Invalid Comma Separated String - Missing Code");
                continue;
            }

            var added = setOfCodes.Add(code);
            if (!added) yield return new ValidationResult($"Duplicate Code: {code}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using .net core. Thanks anyway

Comment: How can I write a regex to check only this three validation? 1.Comma at end 2. Comma at the beginning, 3. No value between commas

Comment: Why are you determined to handle this with regex? In the other answer you were provided with a solution with regex, but you need to separate your errors. The same code works on .NET 4.X by the way, that's why I added the Core in parenthesis, as I was not sure which framework you were using.

Comment: Just some tips though: First of all, if this is a new application, consider the possibility to migrate to .NET Core. Second, regarding the RegEx: Having your validation inside RegEx will be a huge pain to debug and change, it might be better to be more explicit and have the logic in code. There is a famous quote: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.